PyCharm keeps asking to Configure Python Interpreter even though I have the venv folder
PyCharm repeatedly prompts me to "configure python interpreter," even though I haven't changed the path of my project.

Here's the sequence of steps I followed:
I deleted the existing venv folder in my project directory.
I attempted to add a new Python interpreter through PyCharm.
However, after these steps, PyCharm still asks me to configure the Python interpreter. I've tried multiple times to reconfigure it, but the problem persists.
I just tried to run the project after some 2-3 months and today I open it suddenly I get this error.
If you need any other information I will provide it to you immediately. Thank you!
Edit: I have made previous threads about this, though, didn't get any answer yet.

PyCharm has own settings for interpreter - somewhere in File > Settings > Interpretter - and you have to set /path/to/python.exe. If you changed something in venv then PyCharm may have wrong path to python.exe and you have to go again to File > Settings > Interpretter and set correct /path/to/python.exe

PyCharm doesn't care what path you have and if you have venv or not.
It has own file with settings and you have to select /path/to/python.exe in
File > Settings ... (Ctrl+Alt+S) > Project: your_project > Python Interpreter.


And there you have to choose Python Interpreter form list
or you have Add interpreter to set new interpreter.


If later you would have to add some module to this project then you can also do it in this place
File > Settings > Project: your_project > Python Interpreter.

instead of using command pip.
It shows already installed modules (in venv) and you can use + to add new module from list.

Thanks for replying. I did try by doing File > Settings > Project: your_project > Python Interpreter. There it says Invalid python interpreter even though I pointed out the correct python.exe file

if it shows path to this .exe then maybe copy it and run in console to see if it shows some errors - maybe it can explain why it is invalid.
